# SQL Server 2008 error when changing the number of cores

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a virtual machine (virtualbox) with Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2008, running with 4 cores. I wanted to use 6 cores, but when I changed the machine configuration, for some reason SQL Server stopped working. I couldn't start the service - it was giving me an unhandled exception without any extra data.

Does anyone know a fix for that? I can live with 4 cores, but I really want to upgrade to 6.

(I know is this setting, because as soon i went back to 4 cores SQL Server started to work again)

I think there has to be a way to upgrade the machine without reinstalling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the version of SQL Server. Enterprise version may be required.

Comment: I have the standard edition. But if the Express version works this one should too i think... Im going to check the requirements.

Comment: Well, you were right: 4 procs limit. There is a PDF on the SQL Server 2008 Editions Overview that says it. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions.aspx Damn! SqlExpress gives me more power? WTF?! hehehe :-)

Answer (score 2):

> it was giving me an unhandled exception without any extra data

Who was giving an unhandled exception? You app code? Your VM?
SQL Server will restart on 6 cores perfectly fine, you shouldn't have to do anything. It may not *use* all the cores, but it will restart just fine. If SQL Server cannot restart, for any reason, it will add diagnostics in the ERRORLOG, echoed in the system application trace event log as well. Check the ERRORLOG file, as well as `eventvwr.exe`.

Comment: The SQLServer process when trying to start it from SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Did you check the ERRORLOG ?

Comment: Yes, i found on the Log a message saying something like "4 cores detected" allways even when there were 6... And then all my login errors. but nothing that explains it. I also have a SQLExpress installed, this one logs that it found the 6 cores. Also there is the unhandled exceptions, without any more explanations. So i thinks its going to remain a mistery... ;-)

Comment: It seems it was the processor limit of sql server standard. But it wasnt throwing any errors... It just stops working. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem is that the VM sees 6 different processors with 1 core each.